# Angular hold a value in element's scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to store values in an html DOM element's scope. Here is my problem.
I have a JSON array of objects. the array is iterated and create div s .

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="student in students">
 {{student.address}}  
  //if student.address equals previous student address, then
   <div class="newStyle"> </div>
 </div
```

When the array is iterated, if one student's address value is equal to the previous one's address, then the following div should have a new style.
My approach is to solve this is to keep the student's address and at the time of iteration, the student address is stored in a variable (not global) and in the next iteration, new student's address is checked against the previously set address.

Please let me know any way that a value can be hold within the iterating scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `$index` variable which is a iterator offset of the repeated element, (0..length-1):

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="student in students">
  //if student.address equals previous student address, then
   <div data-ng-class="{newStyle: student.address === students[$index-1].address}"> </div>
 </div
```

Note that you can also use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) which will help you automatically add a class name, if the given condition is true, `student.address === students[$index-1].address`.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called $index which will hold the current iteration number, you can use that.

$index will have the current loop count

**student.address==students[$index-1].address**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="student in students">
 {{student.address}}  
  <div ng-if="student.address==students[$index-1].address">
   <div class="newStyle"> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `$index` you can compare values while iteration.

```
   <div data-ng-repeat="student in students">
     {{student.address}}  
      //if student.address equals previous student address, then
       <div ng-class="{newStyle:students[$index-1].address == students[$index].address}"> </div>
     </div
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a function in controller to apply new style if address of student equals to previous previous student address.

---

In you controller define a variable which holds the address and a function to check for duplicate address:

```
var student = "";
$scope.checkAddr=function(param){
student=param;
if(student==param){
return "newStyle";
}
```

---

and in your template :

```
<div data-ng-repeat="student in students">
 {{student.address}}  
  //if student.address equals previous student address, then
   <div ng-class="checkAddr(students[$index].address)"> </div>
 </div
```